# How to fetch 100 items before a DB Object in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `Message` model. I want to fetch the 100 items just before say an `ID = 654`, so those IDs I want to get are 553..653 if no missing IDs in the DB.

The best I could come up with is something like `Message.where(:id => myID-100..myID)` but the problem with this is if there are missing IDs in the DB say 584, 585, 586, 588, 589, 592, 593... and I want exactly 100 items before, and not the ID range.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
Message.where('id < ?', myID).order('id DESC').limit(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use offset query

```
Message.limit(100).offset(654)
```

Please refer [click here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#limit-and-offset)

Comment: hmm i tried this just now, it didn't work. Maybe because offset refers to 'after'? but what I want to retrieve are those before 654. And from the link you've given me, it looks like .offset(NUMBER), NUMBER is Nth position from the start, the problem though is that I think .offset(654) refers to 654th position, and not ID=654 in which case there would be problems if some IDs are missing (say 583, 585, 56) But thanks for this answer. I didn't know this method yet I've learned something new :)

Comment: Offset will skip first 654 elements, regardless of their id. Hence if you have 101 elements, first with id 654, it will skip all the elements.